# ruby on rails - display array in text_field with semicolon delimeters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, forms, mongodb

I have a ruby on rails form that displays values of an array stored in a mongodb document. 
In my _form.html.erb file:
`<%=f.text_field :Tags%>`. This displays the tags array in the text field separated by spaces. 
For example in my tags array I have: **["Recon","Scanning","Network"]**. But in the text field on the web page it is displayed as **"Recon Scanning Network"**.
*I want it to display on the web page as **"Recon; Scannnig; Network"*** because I have a method in my model to split the input by semicolon:

```
def Tags=(values)
  values = values.split(";")
  write_attribute(:Tags, values.reject(&:blank?))
end
```

With it being displayed with just spaces, it doesn't save back to the database properly. It'll save the array as ["Recon Scanning Network"] instead :\

So the question is, how can I get my arrays to display in a `text_field` seperated by semicolons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<%= f.text_field :Tags, value: f.object.Tags.join('; ') %>
```

BTW, converntion in ruby is to write variables and methods names in underscore notation.

Comment: thanks!
it's only one word so I didn't see the need for an underscore?

Comment: @Gcap - yes, no underscore, but it shouldn't start with capital letter.